# Selecting images from a folder and show only images with size less than 1MB android

Tags: android, sqlite, android-sqlite, android-cursor

Hi I have 2 different codes

1. To open the selected folder is imagecursor
2. To show only images of size less than 1Mb is sizeCursor

   ```
   final String[] columns = { MediaStore.Images.Media.DATA, MediaStore.Images.Media.SIZE,MediaStore.Images.Media._ID};

   imagecursor=managedQuery(MediaStore.Images.Media.EXTERNAL_CONTENT_URI, columns,MediaStore.Images.Media.DATA + " like ? ", new String[] {"%/"+foldername+"/%"},null);

   Cursor sizeCursor = managedQuery(MediaStore.Images.Media.EXTERNAL_CONTENT_URI, columns,MediaStore.Images.Media.SIZE + " < ? ",new String[] {"1024"},null);
   ```

Now I want to combine both into a single query, like show the images less than 1MB from selected folder

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The selection parameter is just an SQL expression, so you can combine multiple predicates with AND:

```java
managedQuery(..., ...DATA + " LIKE ? AND " + ...SIZE + " < ?",
             new String[] { "%/"+foldername+"/%", "1024" }, ...);
```

Comment: android.database.sqlite.SQLiteException: near "AND_size": syntax error (code 1): , while compiling: SELECT _data, _size, _id FROM images WHERE (_data like ? AND_size < ?)  ......... This is my logcat am getting error @CL.

Comment: I got it i left a space in that